# Select multiple column in Linq using List

Tags: linq, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList and I fill it using linq. The code example below is working.

> ddlPortal.DataSource = from rows in db.Portals select new
>   {rows.Id, rows.PortalName};

But I need to use it with List variable. What's the problem about the code below?

```
ddlPortal.DataSource = new List<string>(from rows in db.Portals select new {rows.Id.ToString(), rows.PortalName});
```

By the way I need to retrieve two columns for DataValueField and DataTextField of DropDownList .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a `List<string>` but a list of an anonymous type. Use `var`:

```
var dataSource = db.Portals 
    .Select(rows => new {Id = rows.Id.ToString(),Portal =  rows.PortalName} )
    .ToList();

ddlPortal.DataSource = dataSource;
```

Comment: I can use it like that:
ddlPortal.DataSource = new List<string>(from rows in db.Portals select rows.Id.ToString());
It works for retrieving one coloumn. But when I retrieve two columns, it gives me an error.

Comment: @user2953746: _What_ error? Have you set the `DataValueField` to `"ID"` and `DataTextField` to `"Portal"`?

Comment: Yes, I have set.
ddlPortal.DataSource = new List<string>(from rows in db.Portals select rows.Id.ToString(), rows.PortalName);
It gives this error for second one "The name 'rows' does not exist in the current context".
I am not sure how should the syntax be.